# pandas.read_excel() is only passing the first line of the excel sheet as a dataframe label

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, path

I am trying to read an Excel file using pandas.read_excel(). The function is only picking up the very first row of the sheet I am passing and it is returning a 0 by 1 dataframe. Not only it just takes the first row, but it sets it as the dataframe label. I tried passing the path as a handle but it did the same result

```
def read_excel_report(path):
    try:
        #handle = open(path)
        dictionary
        # representing a different worksheet.
        raw_excel = pd.read_excel(path, sheet_name=-1, engine='openpyxl')
        raw_excel = raw_excel.fillna('')

        print("data extracted")
        return raw_excel
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

Comment: Can you detail what is in the sheet? (maybe a table or screenshot), and then add sample values for `raw_excel`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens with the older version of Pandas where Excel files are not created properly.

The **best possible solution** is to upgrade your Python version to 3.8 (or newer) and Pandas version to 1.2 (or newer). Here is Pandas [changelog](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew/v1.2.0.html#what-s-new-in-1-2-0-december-26-2020) for your reference.

If that is not possible then the workaround is to open and close the workbook. i.e. use `openpyxl` library methods `load_workbook` and `close` before using `read_excel` method of Pandas. This will work but it will add several seconds of delay.

Comment: This was indeed the issue. after going from 3.7 to 3.9 the scrip ran as expected. Thank you.